# Mac App Store app rejected because of accessing file system - 2.30

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, review

After developing my first [Mac app](https://github.com/josipbernat/JBLocalizer) I've decided to submit it to the Mac App Store but it got rejected. Basically my app uses NSOpenPanel for reading Xcode project file and NSSavePanel for saving file after it finishes it's work. 
Reviewer pointed out that app is violating 2.30 rule - Apps that do not comply with the Mac OS X File System documentation will be rejected, but I'm unclear why.

When you look at app's workspace you can see it uses CocoaPods for handling dependencies which shouldn't be a problem. Next it has JBLocalizer.framework which is being linked as an embedded library to JBLocalizerApp. JBLocalizerApp is final target sent to the review.

[image]

Here is what reviewer pointed out as a problem:

> 2.30
>
> The application accesses the following location(s):
>
> '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBString.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBPostProcessStringsOperation.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBOperation.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBLoadStringsInFileOperation.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBLoadSourceFilesOperation.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBLoadRootFilesOperation.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBFileController.gcda'
>   '/Users/josipbernat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JBLocalizerApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/JBLocalizer.build/Release/JBLocalizer.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/JBFile.gcda'
>
> The majority of developers encountering this issue are opening files
>   in Read/Write mode instead of Read-Only mode, in which case it should
>   be changed to Read-Only.
>
> Other common reasons for this issue include:
>
> - creating or writing files in the above location(s), which are not valid locations for files to be written as stated in documentation
> - writing to the above location(s) without using a valid app-id as a container for the written files
>
> Please review the "File-System Usage Requirements for the App Store"
>   of Submitting to the Mac App Store for the locations apps are allowed
>   to write and for further guidance.

I'm really not sure how can my app violate access to the library which is being linked to. Any suggestions?

Comment: It appears that your localizer framework isn't even being linked; and how are they coming back with an absolute path to your Xcode DerivedData directory?

Comment: I don't know what are .gcda files but I assume they are dynamically created. Cocoapods adds XcodeEditor pod.
@I'L'I why do you think that framework isn't being linked when I can compile the app and run it on several Macs?

Comment: The red text color of the framework in your screen capture indicates that it is not linked with your target, or is missing from the project. I suspect that it is in your project, since I can see it, however, the one *actually* being linked is missing. I recommend removing the one under `Embedded Libraries` and  `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` and relinking the one in the project navigator.

Comment: I agree that red text color indicates that but at the moment it compiles and runs without a problem. Maybe I find some solution for that. Meanwhile I accepted answer below because it indicates where it might be a problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You've got *Code Coverage* turned on in your project settings.

See [QA1514](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1514/_index.html) on how it's turned on, which should help you turn it off.

Comment: Man I would't find this as an answer for next hundred years! Thanks :)